# Фон с использованием JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нашел вот такой красивый фон: http://www.rudebox.org.ua/beautiful-animated-background-site/
Решил скачать и попробовать. Но проблема в том, что фон не становится фоном, а просто отображается как блок, весь контент при этом съезжает вниз.
Что можно сделать?

Вот код страницы:

```js
var refreshDuration = 10000;
var refreshTimeout;
var numPointsX;
var numPointsY;
var unitWidth;
var unitHeight;
var points;

function onLoad()
{
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('width',window.innerWidth);
    svg.setAttribute('height',window.innerHeight);
    document.querySelector('#bg').appendChild(svg);

    var unitSize = (window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight)/20;
    numPointsX = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth/unitSize)+1;
    numPointsY = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight/unitSize)+1;
    unitWidth = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth/(numPointsX-1));
    unitHeight = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight/(numPointsY-1));

    points = [];

    for(var y = 0; y < numPointsY; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < numPointsX; x++) {
            points.push({x:unitWidth*x, y:unitHeight*y, originX:unitWidth*x, originY:unitHeight*y});
        }
    }

    randomize();

    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if(points[i].originX != unitWidth*(numPointsX-1) && points[i].originY != unitHeight*(numPointsY-1)) {
            var topLeftX = points[i].x;
            var topLeftY = points[i].y;
            var topRightX = points[i+1].x;
            var topRightY = points[i+1].y;
            var bottomLeftX = points[i+numPointsX].x;
            var bottomLeftY = points[i+numPointsX].y;
            var bottomRightX = points[i+numPointsX+1].x;
            var bottomRightY = points[i+numPointsX+1].y;

            var rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

            for(var n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
                var polygon = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'polygon');

                if(rando==0) {
                    if(n==0) {
                        polygon.point1 = i;
                        polygon.point2 = i+numPointsX;
                        polygon.point3 = i+numPointsX+1;
                        polygon.setAttribute('points',topLeftX+','+topLeftY+' '+bottomLeftX+','+bottomLeftY+' '+bottomRightX+','+bottomRightY);
                    } else if(n==1) {
                        polygon.point1 = i;
                        polygon.point2 = i+1;
                        polygon.point3 = i+numPointsX+1;
                        polygon.setAttribute('points',topLeftX+','+topLeftY+' '+topRightX+','+topRightY+' '+bottomRightX+','+bottomRightY);
                    }
                } else if(rando==1) {
                    if(n==0) {
                        polygon.point1 = i;
                        polygon.point2 = i+numPointsX;
                        polygon.point3 = i+1;
                        polygon.setAttribute('points',topLeftX+','+topLeftY+' '+bottomLeftX+','+bottomLeftY+' '+topRightX+','+topRightY);
                    } else if(n==1) {
                        polygon.point1 = i+numPointsX;
                        polygon.point2 = i+1;
                        polygon.point3 = i+numPointsX+1;
                        polygon.setAttribute('points',bottomLeftX+','+bottomLeftY+' '+topRightX+','+topRightY+' '+bottomRightX+','+bottomRightY);
                    }
                }
                polygon.setAttribute('fill','rgba(0,0,0,'+(Math.random()/3)+')');
                var animate = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','animate');
                animate.setAttribute('fill','freeze');
                animate.setAttribute('attributeName','points');
                animate.setAttribute('dur',refreshDuration+'ms');
                animate.setAttribute('calcMode','linear');
                polygon.appendChild(animate);
                svg.appendChild(polygon);
            }
        }
    }

    refresh();

}

function randomize() {
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if(points[i].originX != 0 && points[i].originX != unitWidth*(numPointsX-1)) {
            points[i].x = points[i].originX + Math.random()*unitWidth-unitWidth/2;
        }
        if(points[i].originY != 0 && points[i].originY != unitHeight*(numPointsY-1)) {
            points[i].y = points[i].originY + Math.random()*unitHeight-unitHeight/2;
        }
    }
}

function refresh() {
    randomize();
    for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes.length; i++) {
        var polygon = document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes[i];
        var animate = polygon.childNodes[0];
        if(animate.getAttribute('to')) {
            animate.setAttribute('from',animate.getAttribute('to'));
        }
        animate.setAttribute('to',points[polygon.point1].x+','+points[polygon.point1].y+' '+points[polygon.point2].x+','+points[polygon.point2].y+' '+points[polygon.point3].x+','+points[polygon.point3].y);
        animate.beginElement();
    }
    refreshTimeout = setTimeout(function() {refresh();}, refreshDuration);
}

function onResize() {
    document.querySelector('#bg svg').remove();
    clearTimeout(refreshTimeout);
    onLoad();
}

window.onload = onLoad;
window.onresize = onResize;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Ваш сайт</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="bg"></div>
 <header>
    <nav>
  <ul>
                                <li>Ваше меню</li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>

        <section>

                <article>
                        <header>
                                <h2>Заголовок статьи</h2>
                                <p>Опубликовано <time datetime="2014-01-30T16:31:24+03:00">30 января 2014</time> <a href="#">Автор</a> - <a href="#comments">6 комментариев</a></p>
                        </header>
                        <p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться.</p>
                </article>

                <article>
                        <header>
                                <h2>Заголовок статьи</h2>
                                <p>Опубликовано <time datetime="2014-01-30T16:31:24+03:00">30 января 2014</time> <a href="#">Автор</a> - <a href="#comments">6 комментариев</a></p>
                        </header>
                        <p>Многие программы электронной вёрстки и редакторы HTML используют Lorem Ipsum в качестве текста по умолчанию.</p>
                </article>

        </section>

        <aside>
                <h2>Об авторе</h2>
                <p>Нет никого, кто любил бы боль саму по себе, кто искал бы её и кто хотел бы иметь её просто потому, что это боль..</p>
        </aside>

        <footer>
           <p>Copyright 2014 Ваш сайт</p>
        </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Может потому что у вас `bg` сделан просто блоком, а не фоном? Для примера сделайте его с абсолютным позиционированием

Comment: в примере, который можно скачать на том сайте сделано в виде блока, при этом все работает так, как нужно. позиционирование помогло, но теперь перестали работать ссылки.

Comment: Может потому что там нет контента? Это же пример, фону вы сами стили задаете, и то как вам нужно его расположить, лично ваша прихоть. Проблема которую вы описали, так же можно повторить и с обычной картинкой. Просто картинка в блоке, не будет задним фоном, а сдвинет все.

Comment: картинку я могу прописать в css, а файл с js кодом - нет

Comment: Вы можете стиль задать, через CSS, какие то проблемы? Вы не правильно мыслите в этом направлении

Comment: тогда дайте CSS код, который бы задал фон не картинкой, а .js файлом.

Comment: Вы совсем не понимаете... У вас js уже рулит блоком, в чем проблема дать ему стиль заднего фона? Чтобы он ложился под весь ваш контент. Я говорю именно про это

Comment: #bg дать body не вариант ?

Answer (score 2):

Либо `#bg` задавать абсолютное позиционирование, либо контенту.
К примеру:

```
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```